# Proofing Metropolis Hastings

Tags: probability, markov-chains, density-function

I need to prove the correctness of the Metropolis Hastings algorithm in a presentation.
Sadly, I am having trouble on where to start and what to actually proof.

So if I understood correctly, my final goal is to show that given a proposal function q, it will eventually converge to my target distribution P. My biggest problem is I, that I am having trouble on where I can see statements as given. For instance, i need the underlying PDF to be stationary, but can I just assume this step? My MCMC needs to be ergodic so i know it is an invariant measure, can I just assume that? I know that by Lemma, if a the proposal function is reversible then my then my distribution is invariant.
I am having trouble patching all this information together.

Furthermore, my statistics courses have been some time ago so I am having a bit of trouble with understanding all the technical terms that fly around in those posts.

I know my question is very broad, but can someone try to give me a simple explanations of each steps a MH proof should have?

Comment: The given data is the target distribution $\pi$ (or a multiple thereof). The object constructed by the analyst is the transition probability matrix $P$ (or in continuous space, it is called a transition probability kernel). The Markov chain associated to $P$ just needs to be irreducible, not necessarily aperiodic or recurrent. For the proof of correctness of MH, $P$ is also given. MH transforms the chain associated to $P$ into a chain that is reversible with respect to $\pi$, by reducing some of the transition probabilities (and increasing the "stay still" probabilities to compensate).

Comment: To prove MH is correct, you must show that the transformed chain is reversible with respect to $\pi$ and show that a chain which is reversible with respect to $\pi$ has $\pi$ as its unique invariant distribution.